# How can I save my results in the same file as different columns in case of a 'for-cylce'

Tags: python

```
def get_df():
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    os.chdir("C:/Users/s/Desktop/P")
    for file in os.listdir():
        if file.endswith('.csv'):    

            av_a = np.average(a, axis=0)
            np.savetxt('merged_average.csv', av_a, delimiter=',')
```

I've tried to save it but it always overwrites with the next file and deletes the previous results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment, your code is a bit hard to read, as you are declaring variables which are not used (`df`) and using variables which are not declared (`a`). In the future, try to give a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your problematic code.

I'll still try to give you an interpreted answer:

If you want to store multiple columns from different files next to each other, the job becomes simpler by first acquiring all columns, and then afterwardds save them to the file in a single action.

Here is an interpretation of your code:

```py
def get_df():
    # create an empty list to collect all results
    average_results = []
    os.chdir("C:/Users/s/Desktop/P")
    for file in os.listdir():
        if file.endswith('.csv'):
            a = something(file)  # unknown to me 
            average_results.append(np.average(a, axis=0))
    # convert the results to a 2d numpy matrix,
    # optionally transpose it to get the desired data orientation
    data = np.array(average_results).transpose()
    # save the full dataset
    np.savetxt('merged_average.csv', data , delimiter=',')
```